# Redisson Unable to write command into connection

Tags: redisson

Using redisson 3.13.3 to connect to Redis, but some time an exception throwed, the stack is below, but we can't find the slot or the channel port in the vm.

Unable to write command into connection! Node source: NodeSource [slot=**13580**, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=null], connection: RedisConnection@41548252 [redisClient=[addr=redis://xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx:port], channel=[id: 0xdcc1059a, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:**55134** ! R:/xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx:port], currentCommand=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@174dc5ee(failure: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException)], command=(EVAL), params=[if redis.call('setnx', KEYS[6], ARGV[4]) == 0 then return -1;end;redis.call('expire', KEYS[6], ARGV[..., 6, task.srm.task.4353929913272631325_product04, redisson__timeout__set:{task.srm.task.4353929913272631325_product04}, redisson__idle__set:{task.srm.task.4353929913272631325_product04}, redisson_map_cache_expired:{task.srm.task.4353929913272631325_product04}, redisson__map_cache__last_access__set:{task.srm.task.4353929913272631325_product04}, redisson__execute_task_once_latch:{task.srm.task.4353929913272631325_product04}, 1606882813929, 100, ...], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.LongCodec]], command: (EVAL), params: [local value = redis.call('hget', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]); local expireDate = 92233720368547758; if value ~..., 5, task.srm.tep.usage-v1_product04, redisson__timeout__set:{task.srm.tep.usage-v1_product04}, redisson__idle__set:{task.srm.tep.usage-v1_product04}, redisson__map_cache__last_access__set:{task.srm.tep.usage-v1_product04}, {task.srm.tep.usage-v1_product04}:redisson_options, 1606925138829, PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 38, cap: 256)] after 3 retry attempts